# Unexpected change in male births

Tags: science-fiction

In the event of an unknown virus (or some other phenomenon) that resulted in only female babies being born, what would be the major impact over time?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at what's already happened (not for virus reasons) in [countries where there's a shortage of females.](http://www.newsweek.com/2015/06/05/gender-imbalance-china-one-child-law-backfired-men-336435.html)

But what you are talking about is NO male babies. That would lead to the complete collapse of our population within a generation, because there's no sexual reproduction.

I hope you aren't asking about the societal implications, because those are too far reaching and broad. Asking about THE MAJOR IMPACT--in that case I would say that everything humanity has will be geared towards solving the problem, because that's what we do.

- Sperm Banks from existing males would be in high demand and men would be asked to donate more.
- All the greatest minds in the world would be working on eradicating the virus. Would we come together to solve it? Or would some countries look to only solve it for themselves, in order to eradicate the others? I think that would cause wars if it were the case, but we would be more likely to share information, because if one place has the solution, the rest of the world will do their damndest to get the answer.
- If all else fails, cloning would be quickly be developed, perhaps even concurrently, as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Unless humanity started sperm harvesting existing males and eventually found a way to make artificial sperm, there's no way for reproduction to keep going. So the human race would die out.